# How to drop rows in dataframe if values is <10

Tags: pandas

I want to drop rows in a dataframe if the value is < 10 in a certain column.
With dataframe2.groupby('category_id').Description.count() I can list the items in the dataframe, which works fine. Now i want to drop the rows where the value is < 10.

I tried to create a condition in order to drop the rows, which does not work.

```
if dataframe2.groupby('category_id').Description.count()>= 10:
    dataframe2.drop()
```

The expeceted Output should be that only the rows with the correct condition appear in the dataframe.
The Output is ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 0):

You are close, need [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for `count`s in `Series` with same size like original, also is inverted condition - `>=10` to `<10` for filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
mask = dataframe2.groupby('category_id').Description.transform('count') < 10

df = dataframe2[mask]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of doing this:

## 1. Set the exemple

```py
In [1]:
data = [[2010, 1, 10], [2010, 2, 5], [2010, 4, 6], [2010, 5, 9], [2011, 1, 10], [2011, 3, 5], [2011, 4, 3]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Year', 'Period', 'Amount'])
df

Out [1]:
    Year    Period  Amount
0   2010    1       10
1   2010    2       5
2   2010    4       6
3   2010    5       9
4   2011    1       10
5   2011    3       5
6   2011    4       3
```

## 2. Drop rows based on a condition on a column's value

```py
In [2]:
rows_to_drop = df.loc[df['Year']==2010].index
df.drop(rows_to_drop)

Out [2]:
    Year    Period  Amount
4   2011    1       10
5   2011    3       5
6   2011    4       3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

`df2 = df.drop(df[df['row_name']<10].index)`

`df2` will be the dataframe with dropped rows.